# React/Socket.io not displaying latest message passed down as prop

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, react-state

I am working on a chat application using React and socket.io. Back end is express/node. The relevant components are:
Room.js --> Chat.js --> Messages.js --> Message.js

messageData received from the server is stored in state in Room.js. It is then passed down through Chat.js to Messages.js, where it is mapped onto a series of Message.js components.

When messages are received, they ARE appearing, but only after I start typing in the form again, triggering messageChangeHandler(). Any ideas why the Messages won't re-render when a new message is received and added to state in Room.js? I have confirmed that the state and props are updating everywhere they should be--they just aren't appearing/re-rendering until messageChangeHandler() triggers its own re-render.

Here are the components.

Room.js

```js
export default function Room(props) {
    const [messagesData, setMessagesData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('the use effect ')
        socket.on('broadcast', data => {
            console.log(messagesData)
            let previousData = messagesData
            previousData.push(data)
            // buildMessages(previousData)
            setMessagesData(previousData)
        })
    }, [socket])


    console.log('this is messagesData in queue.js', messagesData)

    return(
        // queue counter will go up here
        // <QueueDisplay />

        // chat goes here
        <Chat 
            profile={props.profile} 
            messagesData={messagesData}
        />

    )
}
```

Chat.js

```js
export default function Chat(props) {
    // state
    const [newPayload, setNewPayload] = useState({
        message: '',
        sender: props.profile.name
    })
    // const [messagesData, setMessagesData] = useState([])
    const [updateToggle, setUpdateToggle] = useState(true)


    const messageChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setNewPayload({... newPayload, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    const messageSend = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (newPayload.message) {
            socket.emit('chat message', newPayload)
            setNewPayload({
                message: '',
                sender: props.profile.name  
            })
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <div id='chatbox'>
            <div id='messages'>
                <Messages messagesData={props.messagesData} />
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={messageSend}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="message" 
                    id="message" 
                    placeholder="Start a new message" 
                    onChange={messageChangeHandler} 
                    value={newPayload.message}
                    autoComplete='off'
                />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Messages.js

```js
export default function Messages(props) {
    return(
        <>
        {props.messagesData.map((data, i) => {
            return <Message key={i} sender={data.sender} message={data.message} />
        })}
        </>
    )
}
```

Message.js

```js
export default function Message(props) {
    return(
        <div key={props.key}>
            <p>{props.sender}</p>
            <p>{props.message}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to set the state in Room component like `setMessagesData([...messageData,  data])`?

Comment: @AWolf That's what I had originally, and I just tried it again. For some reason, that overwrites the state entirely, meaning the state will only hold the most recent message, so it won't work. Thanks for checking.

Comment: That's because `useEffect()` doesn't have a dependency on `messagesData`, so `messagesData` was changing outside `useEffect()` but not inside it. More details in my overly-elaborate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that your `useEffect()` function does what you think it does.

## Red flag

Your brain should generate an immediate red flag if you see a `useEffect()` function that uses variables declared in the enclosing scope (in a closure), but those variables are not listed in `useEffect()`'s dependencies (the `[]` at the end of the `useEffect()`)

## What's actually happening

In this case, `messagesData` in being used inside `useEffect()` but not declared as a dependency. What happens is that after the first `broadcast` is received and `setMessagesData` is called, `messagesData` is no longer valid inside `useEffect()`. It refers to an array, from the closure when it was last run, which isn't assigned to `messageData` any longer. When you call `setMessagesData`, React knows that the value has been updated, and re-renders. It runs the `useState()` line and gets a new `messagesData`. `useEffect()`, which is a *memoized function*, does **NOT** get recreated, so it's still using `messagesData` from a previous run.

## How to fix it

### Clean up `useEffect()`

Before we start, let's eliminate some of the noise in the function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('broadcast', data => {
            setMessagesData([...messagesData, data])
        })
    }, [socket])
```

This is functionally equivalent to your code, minus the `console.log()` messages and the extra variable.

Let's go one step further and turn the handler into a one-liner:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('broadcast', data => setMessagesData([...messagesData, data]));
    }, [socket])
```

### Add missing dependencies

Now, let's add the missing dependencies!

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('broadcast', data => setMessagesData([...messagesData, data]));
    }, [socket, messagesData])
```

Technically, we also depend on `setMessagesData()`, but [React has this to say about `setState()` functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

### Too many cooks

The `useEffect()` function is looking good, but we still depend on `messagesData`. This is a problem, because every time `socket` receives a `broadcast`, `messagesData` changes, so `useEffect()` is re-run. Every time it is re-run, it adds a new handler/listener for `broadcast` messages, which means that when the next message is received, every handler/listener calls `setMessagesData()`. The code might still accidentally work, at least logic-wise, because listeners are usually called, synchronously, in the order in which they were registered, and I believe that if multiple `setState()` calls are made during the same render, React only re-renders once using the final `setState()` call. But it will definitely be a memory leak, since we have no way to unregister all of those listeners.

This tiny problem would normally end up being a huge pain to solve, because to fix this problem, we would need to unregister the old listener every time we registered a new one. And to unregister a listener, we call `removeListener()` function with the same function we registered - but we don't have that function anymore. Which means we need to save the old function as state or memoize it, but now we also have another dependency for our `useEffect()` function. Avoiding a continuous loop of infinite re-renders turns out to be non-trivial.

### The trick

It turns out that we don't have to jump through all of those hoops. If we look closely at our `useEffect()` function, we can see that we don't actually use `messagesData`, except to set the new value. We're taking the old value and appending to it.

The React devs knew that this was a common scenario, so there's actually a built-in helper for this. `setState()` can accept a function, which will immediately be called with the previous value as an argument. The result of this function will be the new state. It sounds more complicated than it is, but it looks like this:

```
setState(previous => previous + 1);
```

or in our specific case:

```
setMessagesData(oldMessagesData => [...oldMessagesData, data]);
```

Now we no longer have a dependency on `messagesData`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('broadcast', data => setMessagesData(oldMessagesData => [...oldMessagesData, data]);
    }, [socket])
```

### Being polite

Remember earlier when we talked about memory leaks? It turns out this can still happen with our latest code. This Component may get mounted and unmounted multiple times (for example, in a Single-Page App when the user switches pages). Each time this happens, a new listener is registered. The polite thing to do is to have `useEffect()` return a functions which will clean up. In our case this means unregistering/removing the listener.

First, save the listener before registering it, then return a function to remove it

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = data => setMessagesData(oldMessagesData => [...oldMessagesData, data];
        socket.on('broadcast', listener);
        return () => socket.removeListener('broadcast', listener);
    }, [socket])
```

Note that our listener will still be dangling if `socket` changes, and since it's not clear in the code where `socket` comes from, whatever changes that will also have to remove all old listeners, e.g. `socket.removeAllListeners()` or `socket.removeAllListeners('broadcast')`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the useEffect in room to contain the following fixed the issue:

````js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('the use effect ')
        socket.on('broadcast', data => {
            console.log(messagesData)
            // let previousData = messagesData
            // previousData.push(data)
            // setMessagesData(previousData)
            setMessagesData(prev => prev.concat([data]))
        })
    }, [socket])```
````